# PHP (check or uncheck) a checkbox from Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

So I'm using a checkbox to insert data into MySql database.
When check it stores "finish"
When unchecked if stores "pending"

Now for an edit feature, I have to fetch and display the data from the database. I need the checkbox to be checked or unchecked if it is stored as finish or pending. Appreciate your help, thank you.

The code to fetch the data is shown below:

```
    <?php
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM ebook WHERE Eid='" . $Eid . "'");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
```

Displaying data and checkbox:

```
   <html>
   <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $rows["Title"]; ?>">
   <input class="tgl tgl-flip" id="chk" type="checkbox" name="chk" />
   </html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a condition echo inside the input.

```
   <input class="tgl tgl-flip" id="chk" type="checkbox" name="chk" <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'finish') { echo "checked"; } ?>/>
```

Comment: that should do it